# How do I write to files in ARM assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, io, arm, system-calls

I am learning ARM assembly on my raspberry pi, and I am trying to write to a file called "user_data.txt". I do know how to create a file, like so...

```
.data

.balign 1
file_name: .asciz "user_data.txt"

.text

.global _start
_start:
    MOV R7, #8
    LDR R0, =file_name
    MOV R1, #0777
    SWI 0
_end:
    MOV R7, #1
    SWI #0
```

...but, as I said, I can't figure out how I would write to this file. I have looked at other tutorials, but none that I looked at explain what each line does. I understand that I would move 4 into R7, in order to call the sys_write system call, but how would I tell ARM the file name I want to write to?

Can anyone give some code which clearly shows and explains some ARM that writes to a file?

Thanks,

- primecubed

Comment: You got a file descriptor back from the [`creat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/creat.2.html) call. Pass that to [`write`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html). Consult standard unix manuals or tutorials, this is not asm specific.

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Comment: Ah ok, I see, thanks a lot for your response :) Is the file descriptor in R0 then or something? Also what do you mean by 'this is not asm specific'?

Comment: And I am using Rasbian

Comment: Yes, it's in `r0`. Not asm specific in the sense that it is standard unix file handling.

Comment: Oh ok I see, so in the _start label, it would be something like this:

MOV R7, #8
LDR R0, =file_name
MOV R1, #0777
SWI #0

MOV R7, #4
LDR R1, =message
MOV R2, #11
SWI #0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you wanted code:

```
.data

.balign 1
file_name: .asciz "user_data.txt"

.text

.global _start
_start:
    MOV R7, #8
    LDR R0, =file_name
    MOV R1, #0777
    SWI 0
    MOV R7, #4         ;write(int fd, void* buf, int len)
    LDR R1, =file_name ;buf
    MOV R2, #9         ;len
    SWI 0
    MOV R7, #6         ;close(int fd)
    SWI 0
_end:
    MOV R7, #1
    SWI #0
```

This will (for simplicity) write 9 chars of file_name (user_data) into the file and close it. Note that R0 always holds fd.

The manpages (https://linux.die.net/man/2/creat, https://linux.die.net/man/2/write) and this table (https://syscalls.w3challs.com/?arch=arm_thumb) are useful resources I often consult.